# Application is running even after uninstall

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I have a windows app and an installer created using WIX.
The APP is having a tray icon and works based on that.

During uninstall, the app has to be exit.
I have added a custom action for that.

```
<CustomAction Id="ExitApp" FileKey="MYFILE" ExeCommand="/exit" Return="ignore"  Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="ExitApp" Before="RemoveFiles"> (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>

</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Then the EXE is invoked with commandline /exit
and the APP Kills all the running instances.

```
String ^procName = Process::GetCurrentProcess()->ProcessName;
array<Process^> ^processes = Process::GetProcessesByName(procName);
    if(args[0] == "/exit")
        {
            for each (Process^ p in processes)
            {
                int retry = 0;
                while(!p->HasExited && retry<5)
                {
                p->CloseMainWindow();
                p->Kill();
                p->WaitForExit();
                }
            }           
            return 0;
    }
```

But some times the running instance of the app is not getting quit (Especially when there is a window visible).

If the app is running, sometimes the dialog with the message "The Following applications should be closed before continuing" is displayed.

The issue occurs when user clicks the Ignore button on this.
But in most cases the app gets quit, even the Ignore is clicked. But some times it is not.

I have tried adding logs, and found that the Code is executed always but still the app remains without getting terminated, and the window is accessible.
Also we cannot find the running instance, once we manually quit the applicaion
But the Application files are removed from the install location.

Is there any specific reason that the app is not getting quit.

I have tried changing the execute sequece to before/ after install validate etc.
But still the result is same.

Is there any way to make the app quit always.

Comment: I think the issue might be that tray apps don't have a main window when they are minimized in the tray. You know WiX already has a util  CloseApplication you could try? Otherwise your code will probably need to send an explicit message to your app that the app understands and then shuts down. Or it could just integrate with Restart Manager.

Comment: The 2 options you said was tried already.

Comment: Anyway it has solved by invoking taskill.exe using WixCA